# Why final argument modifier is not inherited in concrete impementation method signature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Considering we have a method signature like this

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    protected abstract void doStuff(final MyArg arg);
}
```

Why does concrete implementation no longer needs to fulfill the `final` modifier in the method signature?

```
public class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    protected void doStuff(MyArg arg) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Now, I know that you still **can** make the argument `final` in concrete signature, but why aren't you're forced to? What's the reason for skipping it, and bonus question, why do code generators like `Intellij` also skip it by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not a parameter is `final` has no effect observable to the caller, just as the caller doesn't need to know if the method's local variables are `final` or not. It's not part of the method's contract; the only reason the parameter's `final` modifier appears in the signature is because that's where the parameter is declared.

The concrete overridden method doesn't need to "fulfill" the `final` modifier because there is no obligation to fulfill.

Comment: If that's the case, then why can you even declare argument final in abstract/interface method signature? What does that achieve?

Comment: That's a good question; it achieves nothing. I guess it's allowed simply because the spec doesn't forbid it.

Answer (score 6):

A parameter being `final` or not has absolutely no effect on the caller of the method.

It's purely a flag to indicate that within the body of the method the parameter should not be changed.

Since any such change would only be visible within the method body, no caller could care (or observe) if a parameter is final or not.

A [methods signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) depends on the parameter types only. It does not depend on the parameter *names* or the presence of the `final` keyword.

Comment: If that's the case, then why can you even declare argument final in abstract/interface method signature? What does that achieve?

Comment: @Ben It achieves absolutely nothing. The language designers simply used the same syntax for interface parameters as for class parameters, and didn't add a rule preventing `final` on an `abstract` method. --- Why not? They probably didn't even think of it.

Comment: They may well have thought of it later, by which time, changing it would break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Implementations of interfaces have to have the same or wider signatures as the interfaces.

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they
>   have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and,
>   after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type
>   parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> ```
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.
> ```

So the keyword final has no impact whatsorever on the equality of a method signature.

Comment: That's true for access modifiers, but doesn't have a whole lot to do with argument mutability. I don't see how making an argument mutable makes it a more open implementation, final is entirely up for the implementation of the method. So if putting `final` on does nothing, why is that even allowed?